# An alternative solution or hold loop execution until condition satisfies

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

Can we hold "for" loop execution until specific condition is  satisfied. I have a popup(Alert) inside a for loop. The popup asking user confirmation(Agree or Cancel option). But loop doesn't wait for the condition. Based on popup "Agree" or "Cancel", I need to continue the loop execution.

Comment: why do you need an alert in a loop?can you provide a working example?

Comment: That's not an alert. It's an message popup.

Comment: ok message popup, similar to a alert

Comment: what's with that array?

Comment: Please paste your current code, as we don't know what this popup does or what it is even. I am assuming it's not the built-in JS alert.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the internal confirmation popup execute in an async function like this -

```js
function asyncFunction(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let response = confirm("Agree for iteration " + i);
        resolve(response);
    });
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Wait for the response of the asyncFunction to proceed to next iteration
    asyncFunction(i).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
        // Further processing of the user's response
    });
}
```

Another alternate would be to eliminate the `for` loop and have a recursive function in place, like this -

```js
var iter = 10;
      
function asyncFunction(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let response = confirm("Iterations left: " + i + ". Proceed to next iteration?");
        resolve(response);
    });
}

function iterator(iter){
    // Wait for the response of the asyncFunction to proceed to next iteration
    asyncFunction(iter).then((response)=>{
        // Proceed if true
        if(response) {
            iterator(iter-1);
        }
    });
}
      
iterator(iter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use es6 aync/await concept

```js
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}

f();
```

Comment: it's tagged sapui5 which is generally not transpiled to es5, and enterprise customers often have to support older versions of IE